# Order of shell expansions: command substitution versus arithmetic expansion

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

Consider the following snippet being entered at the command line in bash:

```
$ echo $(( $(wc -l letter.txt | cut -c1-4)/66 + 1))
```

Supposing `letter.txt` exists and has 66*4 lines, then this puts the string 5 on the command line. Now what I cannot follow is how this conclusion follows based on what I know about command line processing.

My book (Sobell's *A Practical Guide to Linux*, 4e) says

> The Bourne Again Shell scans each token for the various types of expansion and sub- stitution in the following order. Most of these processes expand a word into a single word. Only brace expansion, word splitting, and pathname expansion can change the number of words in a command (except for the expansion of the variable "$@"— see page 474).
>
> 1. Brace expansion (next page)
> 2. Tilde expansion (page 368)
> 3. Parameter and variable expansion (page 368)
> 4. Arithmetic expansion (page 369)
> 5. Command substitution (page 371)
> 6. Word splitting (page 372)
> 7. Pathname expansion (page 372)
> 8. Process substitution (page 374)
> 9. Quote removal (page 374)

Based on the above, it would seem that the arithmetic expansion would evaluate first and, if so, the token `$(wc -l letter.txt | cut -c1-4)` is not a valid operand for the integer arithmetic which bash deals with. What is my way out here/what am I not understanding?

Comment: That listed order also implies that filenames that resulted from globs would be parsed for process substitutions, i.e. that running `echo *` in a directory containing a file called `<(rm -rf ~/*)` would delete the contents of your home directory. Luckily, that's not how it works. I can't imagine how they've figured that order would make any sense.

Comment: I see what you mean now, thanks for pointing that out! Where does process substitution fit in the hierarchy then? It doesn't seem to be mentioned at all in the answer I accepted below. @ilkkachu

Comment: Right, I thought there was a link to the [reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) here already. It says _"On systems that can support it, there is an additional expansion available: process substitution. This is performed at the same time as tilde, parameter, variable, and arithmetic expansion and command substitution."_

Comment: Superb! Thanks again, @ilkkachu . I've marked this down as an error in my book.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your book is not exactly correct. See `man bash` for the exact order:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable  expansion, arithmetic  expansion, and  command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and pathname expansion.

Note the usage of commas and *semicolons*. The parameter, variable, and arithmetic expansions plus the command substitution all happen with the same order.

The manual says the following about arithmetic expansion:

> All tokens in the expression undergo parameter and  variable expansion,  command  substitution, and quote removal.

And command substitution is described as

> ... executing command in a subshell environment

which means all expansions take place when nested from inside out.

```
$ echo $((1 + $(echo $((2+$(printf %s 3))))))
6
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much! This book has been really good so far so I'm a bit surprised it would make what seemingly appears to be an error. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: I'm not surprised at all. Accurate shell documentation not written by either a standards body _actively maintaining a standard to which shells conform_ or someone who is personally involved in implementing a major shell is vanishingly rare; published books are no exception.